# unable to select entire row if rowspan is applied in bootstrap table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working on a task where I need to select entire row even if rowspan is applied.

**Fiddle:** https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/91/

**HTML:**

```
    <table class="table table-bordered table-hover">
        <thead><th>Name</th><th>Score</th></thead>
        <tbody id="DynamicData"></tbody>
    </table>
```

**JS:**

```
var dataList = [];
var dataRow1 = {};
dataRow1.Name = "Test User 1";
dataRow1.Scores = [10, 22, 32];
dataList.push(dataRow1);

var dataRow2 = {};
dataRow2.Name = "Test User 2";
dataRow2.Scores = [34];
dataList.push(dataRow2);

var dataRow3 = {};
dataRow3.Name = "Test User 3";
dataRow3.Scores = [20, 42, 92];
dataList.push(dataRow3);

var dynamicData = $('#DynamicData');

$.each(dataList, function(i, data){
    if (data.Scores.length > 1)
    {
        $.each(data.Scores, function (j, score){
            if (j == 0)
            {
                dynamicData.append('<tr class="selectable-row"><td rowspan="'+data.Scores.length+'">'+data.Name+'</td><td>'+score+'</td></tr>');             }
            else
            {
                dynamicData.append('<tr class="selectable-row"><td>'+score+'</td></tr>'); 
            }
        });
    }
    else if (data.Scores.length == 1)      
    {
        dynamicData.append('<tr class="selectable-row"><td>'+data.Name+'</td><td>'+data.Scores[0]+'</td></tr>');
    }    
});

//event
$('.selectable-row').on('click', function(){
    dynamicData.find('tr').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

**CSS:**

```
.selected{background-color:skyblue;}
```

**Current:**

If I click on a cell in first row, the Name (Test User 1) and Score (10) is selected.

[image]

**Expectation:**

When I click on any cell in first row, the Name (Test User 1) and All scores cells (10, 22 and 32) should be selected.

[image]

Any suggestions is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to select all rows which are part of a `rowspan`, you will have to use their own `tbody` to group them together and then style on the `tbody` instead.

So, you will have to restructure your table generation a little bit, to enclose all your related rows in a `tbody` of its own. Just use your `.selected` class on your `tbody` and listen for `click` event on the `tbody` instead of `tr`.

Also, because we are now using a `tbody`, you cannot use bootstrap's `table-hover` class on `table` for hovering. Will have to use your user-defined style on `tbody`.

***Example Snippet***: (*Omitting the Javascript table generation part in this example. Hope you get the idea.*)

```js
$('table').on('click', 'tbody', function(){
    $('table').find('tbody').removeClass('selected');
    $(this).addClass('selected');
});
```

```css
tbody:hover tr { background-color: #eee;  }
tbody.selected tr { background-color: #acf; }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered">
    <thead><tr><th>Name</th><th>Score</th></tr></thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td rowspan="3">Test User 1</td><td>10</td></tr>
  <tr><td>22</td></tr>
  <tr><td>32</td></tr>
 </tbody>
 <tbody>
  <tr><td>Test User 2</td><td>34</td></tr>
 </tbody> 
 <tbody>
  <tr><td rowspan="3">Test User 3</td><td>20</td></tr>
  <tr><td>42</td></tr>
  <tr><td>92</td></tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

*Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/abhitalks/52jjtoy6/*

Comment: Yes, I got the idea and able to apply in my application. One thing I am observing is, as we are wrapping rows in tbody, the borders are now thicker. But, I will be able to adjust the css and fix them.

Comment: @VimalanJayaGanesh: Yes. That is coming from the Bootstrap's style. Specifically, you need to override this rule - `.table>tbody+tbody {
    border-top: 2px solid #ddd;
}`

Answer (score 1):

See the example:
https://jsfiddle.net/99x50s2s/93/

Basically, you need to calculate the count of row span, and apply selected class accordingly:

```
$('.selectable-row').on('click', function(){
dynamicData.find('tr').removeClass('selected');
$(this).addClass('selected');

// Find span count in first td. Select next rows.
var spanCount = $(this).find('td:first').attr('rowspan');
$(this).nextAll().slice(0, spanCount - 1).addClass('selected');
```

});

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to write so much JS, The effect can be achieved easily using only CSS. 
Here is the code, Just edit as per your need.

CSS:

```
.student{border:1px solid #ccc; width:300px;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:15px;}
.student .name{ width:99px; height:inherit}
.student .score
{
width:200px;
border-left:1px solid #eee;
}
.score table{ width:100%}
.score td{ border-top:1px solid #CCC;}
.score table tr:first-child td{ border-top:1px solid transparent;}
.student:hover{background:#EEE}
.name,.score{float:left}
.student:after{display:block;content:""; clear:both; height:1px}


<div class='student'>
<div class='name'>Test User1</div>  
<div class='score'>
        <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='student'>
<div class='name'>Test User1</div>  
<div class='score'>
        <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='student'>
<div class='name'>Test User1</div>  
<div class='score'>
        <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div class='student'>
<div class='name'>Test User1</div>  
<div class='score'>
        <table>
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         
        <tr><td>1</td></tr>         

        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```